# Route states not working properly when declaring them in the same file

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a project where everything is modular, the order in which the files are loaded at index.html is:

```
app
|– client
|  |– modules
|  |  |– products
|  |  |  |– conditions
|  |  |  |  |- crud
|  |  |  |  |- conditions.module.js #6
|  |  |  |  └─ conditions.routes.js #7
|  |  |  |– brands
|  |  |  |  |- crud
|  |  |  |  |- brands.module.js #4
|  |  |  |  └─ brands.routes.js #5
|  |  |  |- crud
|  |  |  |- products.module.js #1
|  |  |  └─ products.routes.js #2
|  |  |- ...
```

The thing is that if I declare the state `home.products.conditions` at *products.routes.js* everything works fine, I mean all the child states declared at *brand.routes.js* work, but if I declare `home.products.conditions` at *conditions.routes.js* before all it's childs, some routes, specifically `home.products.conditions.create` doesn't work! same for `home.products.brands`

Any ideas?

Here's the way I register states:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module( 'app.products' )
        .constant( 'states', getRouteStates() )
        .config( [ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'states', stateConfigurator ] );

    function stateConfigurator( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, states ) {

        states.forEach( function ( state ) {

            $stateProvider.state( state.name, state.config );

        } );

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( '/' );

    }

    function getRouteStates() {
        return [
            {
                name: 'home.products.create',
                config: {
                    url: '/nuevo',
                    views: {
                        'dashboard-heading@': {
                            template: '<b>Completar el formulario</b>'
                        },
                        'dashboard-body@': {
                            templateUrl: './modules/purchases/products/create-product/create-product.form.html',
                            controller: 'CreateProductController',
                            controllerAs: 'vm'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'home.products.list',
                config: {
                    url: '/listado',
                    views: {
                        'dashboard-heading@': {
                            template: '<b>Lista de Productos</b>'
                        },
                        'dashboard-body@': {
                            templateUrl: './modules/purchases/products/read-product/products-list.view.html',
                            controller: 'ReadProductController',
                            controllerAs: 'vm'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ];
    }

})();
```

Comment: Angular doesn't depend on the file structure, hence it is totally irrelevant. Something wrong happens during bundling process, and it looks like you omitted any valuable information on that.

Comment: @estus alright, what would you like to know about the app? I don't really know what else to post, I don't understand the problem, and there's no error output...

Comment: The code you've posted looks ok. I guess you could strip down [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to bare minimum when the problem is reproducible and post the bundled script. The plunker won't hurt also. And it is not uncommon that the one figures out the problem by his own when doing that.